# Routing from Login page to app angular2

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

Am new to working with angular2 and am developing an app. I am stuck at the login page. After I clicked the login button the url changes but the view doesn't. I have 3 components: main (defining the route), login and app.

### main.ts

```typescript
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, RouteConfig, RouterOutlet } from 'angular2/router';
import { app } from './app.component';
import { Login } from './login.component';

@Component({
    selector: 'main',
    template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
    directives: [RouterOutlet]
})

@RouteConfig([
    { path: '/app/:searchId', name: 'App', component: App },
    { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: Login,useAsDefault:true }
])
export class RouteComponent {

}
```

### Login

```typescript
//some imports...
@Component({
template:`<button (ngSubmit)=onSubmit(username,password)>`})//did not include other labels and inputs etc`
export class Login{
  onSubmit(username:string,password:string)
  {
    some authentication....
    this._router.navigate(['App',{searchId:this.sessionId}]);
  }
}
```

### boot.ts

```typescript
import { bootstrap  } from 'angular2/platform/browser';
import{provide} from "angular2/core";
import { ROUTER_PROVIDERS,LocationStrategy,HashLocationStrategy } from 'angular2/router';
import { RouteComponent } from './main';

bootstrap(RouteComponent,[
  ROUTER_PROVIDERS,
  provide(LocationStrategy,{useClass:HashLocationStrategy})
]);
```

Comment: try `this._router.navigate(['/App',{searchId:this.sessionId}]);`

Comment: tried....nothing changed

Comment: seems like this issue https://github.com/angular/router/issues/353

Answer (score 2):

If the browser location is updated but not the view it's because no routes are found.
You should try to update this line

```
this._router.navigate(['App',{searchId:this.sessionId}]);
```

with

```
this._router.navigate(['../App',{searchId:this.sessionId}]);
```

The router instance in `login` is a child of the one you have in `main`

Comment: it is throwing an error saying the link has too many "../" segments

Answer (score 0):

I see a typo in your code when importing the `App` component:

```
import { Component } from 'angular2/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES, Router, RouteConfig, RouterOutlet } from 'angular2/router';
import { app } from './app.component'; // <--------
import { Login } from './login.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'main',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>',
  directives: [RouterOutlet]
})
@RouteConfig([
  { path: '/app/:searchId', name: 'App', component: App },
  { path: '/login', name: 'Login', component: Login,useAsDefault:true }
])
export class RouteComponent {

}
```

You should use this instead:

```
import { App } from './app.component';
```

The `onSubmit` method was also `OnSubmit` in the `Login` component...

Comment: checked that...it was typo in the question...sorry m new to stackoverflow as well

Comment: no....i use Visual Studio code...any typos will throw an error...i have just illustrated the logic which i think has a major issue m not able to find out